# Exclude or Remove method get TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like exclude or remove the method get in my class, example

```
export class User {

  password: string;

  public setPassword(password: string): void {
   this.password= password;
  }

  // exclude or remove
  public getPassword(): string {
   return this.password;
  }
}
```

I would don't want to send this data to firebase Database

Answer (score 0):

A general way to shed methods from an instance is to use the JSON parser, which will result in just the properties remaining...

```
const user = new User();
user.password = 'test';

const propsOnly = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
```

This results in an object with a `password` property and no methods - and the JSON parser is more robust that something we might write ourselves. This trick is also robust to future methods that are added to the User class.

If you are sending JSON data to the API, you don't need to do this as the serialization will remove the methods anyway.

Comment: but the way I'm to making I use the method : user = new User()   .....     this.user.setPassword(value)

Comment: I'm record data in firebase in authentication and database, but I dont want to send the password to database .....

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep `getPassword` only to yourself would be to make its reference known only to you.

```
const GET_PASSWORD = Symbol();

export class User {
  private password: string;

  constructor(password: string) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public setPassword(password: string): void {
   this.password= password;
  }

  public [GET_PASSWORD](): string {
   return this.password;
  }
}

const password = new User('foo')[GET_PASSWORD]()
```

Only the ones having access to `GET_PASSWORD` symbol will be able to call the method.

Although it's not the most elegant approach, and it probably makes sense to wrap your class into another one — this time without a getter.

Comment: You can't hide property this way, because there is `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`

Comment: You still need to have the symbol to dereference their values.

Comment: Aand you can find it with the `Object` method defined above. I mean symbols make it harder, but not impossible.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an example on how to obtain the `password` without having `GET_PASSWORD`?

Comment: I hope you can understand it yourself after having a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols#Examples) but if not, ask me and I'll provide the code.

Comment: I have seen it — and in order to call `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` you need to construct `obj`, and for that you need to have explicit references to `a` and `b` —  or `GET_PASSWORD ` in this case. The whole point of my proposed solution is not to share this key.

Comment: The question is ambiguous (and weird) and this can lead to our different understanding of it. But still I find it hard to understand what you are trying to suggest. You can't hide the key because you can find it. And if the object is serialized with `JSON.stringify`, even regular, non-symbol methods are not included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with firebase, but I suspect your concern is false. Even if not, removing a method would hardly help to remove it.

But if you really want to remove a method, then it is done this way:

```
let user = new User()
delete user.getPassword
```

If you however want to remove password from an object instance, then you should do something like this instead:

```
let user = new User()
user.password = ''
```